# Disable EditText blinking cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext

Does anyone know how to disable the blinking cursor in an `EditText` view?

Answer (score 397, accepted):

You can use either the xml attribute `android:cursorVisible="false"` or programatically:

- java: `view.setCursorVisible(false)`
- kotlin: `view.isCursorVisible = false`

Comment: Awesome, this together with onclicklistener that makes it visible gives the correct behaviour :)

Comment: @cerin is there a way to hide the blue marker so I can disable the paste, but keep the cursor visible so the user will see where is he in the field?

Comment: Is it possible to disable just the blinking itself, and not the cursor?

Comment: this code `view.setCursorVisible(false);` works very fine to solve programmatically

Answer (score 44):

Perfect Solution that goes further to the goal

Goal: Disable the blinking curser when `EditText` is not in focus, and enable the blinking curser when `EditText` is in focus. Below also opens keyboard when `EditText` is clicked, and hides it when you press done in the keyboard.

1) Set in your xml under your `EditText`:

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

2) Set onClickListener:

```
iEditText.setOnClickListener(editTextClickListener);

OnClickListener editTextClickListener = new OnClickListener() 

{

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
         if (v.getId() == iEditText.getId()) 
        {
            iEditText.setCursorVisible(true);
        }

    }
};
```

3) then `onCreate`, capture the event when done is pressed using `OnEditorActionListener` to your `EditText`, and then `setCursorVisible(false)`.

```
//onCreate...

iEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                    iEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
                if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(iEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER will not work for all keyboards. You'll need to specifically mention     android:imeOptions="actionDone"  in the layout and then handle     EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE also.

Comment: Great answer just should replace on click with on touch because some time edit text gain focus without on click so in this case the cursor wont be shown

Answer (score 15):

You can use following code for enabling and disabling edit text cursor by programmatically.

> To Enable cursor

```
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
```

> To Disable cursor

```
    editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

> Using XML enable disable cursor

```
   android:cursorVisible="false/true"
   android:focusable="false/true"
```

> To make edit_text Selectable to (copy/cut/paste/select/select all)

```
   editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

> To focus on touch mode write following lines in XML

```
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
```

> programmatically

```
  editText.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

> To clear focus on touch mode

```
  editText.clearFocus()
```

Comment: editText.clearFocus() is what I was looking for. Thanks!! +1

Answer (score 6):

simple add this line into your parent layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with setting cursor visibility to true and false may be a problem since it removes the cursor until you again set it again and at the same time field is editable which is not good user experience.

so instead of using

```
setCursorVisible(false)
```

just do it like this

```
        editText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false)
        editText2.clearFocus()
        editText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
```

The above code removes the focus which in turn removes the cursor. And enables it again so that you can again touch it and able to edit it. Just like normal user experience.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I wanted to enable/disable the cursor when the edit is focused.

In your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            EditText edit = ((EditText) v);
            Rect outR = new Rect();
            edit.getGlobalVisibleRect(outR);
            Boolean isKeyboardOpen = !outR.contains((int)ev.getRawX(), (int)ev.getRawY());
            System.out.print("Is Keyboard? " + isKeyboardOpen);
            if (isKeyboardOpen) {
                System.out.print("Entro al IF");
                edit.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edit.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

            edit.setCursorVisible(!isKeyboardOpen);

        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want `edit.setCursorVisible(!isKeyboardOpen);` to be `edit.setCursorVisible(isKeyboardOpen);` so that the cursor is visible when the keyboard is present.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore the `Edittext` from the starting of activity, `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` will help you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

> This `LinearLayout` with your `Edittext`.

Answer (score 3):

add android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in root layout, when edit text will be clicked at that time cursor will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change focus to another view (ex: Any textview or Linearlayout in the XML) using

   ```
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   ```
2. set addTextChangedListener to edittext in Activity.
3. and then on aftertextchanged of Edittext put `edittext.clearFocus()`;

This will enable the cursor when keyboard is open and disable when keyboard is closed.

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin your_edittext.isCursorVisible = false

Comment: Please, format the markup. You can do that by indenting the code by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

rootLayout.findFocus().clearFocus();