# How can I hide extended cursor on Android?

Tags: android

Hi I m trying to hide that cursor which you can see on my images captured from different device.I need to know what is the exact name of that component, or how can I hide it? It is indicating the cursor on EditText.

Thank You for all your answers

[image: image3]

[image: imag2]

[image: image1]

Comment: Is this what you need? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582702/disable-edittext-blinking-cursor

Comment: Yes I have tried it but it hide only the blinking black line not theimage under it