# remove cursor from editText

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable EditText blinking cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582702/disable-edittext-blinking-cursor)

I have 2 editText fields in my activity with some text in it:

```
EditText nameText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_name_text);
nameText.setText(Info.getName());

EditText phone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
phone.setText(Info.getPhoneNo());
```

When I run the app on my device and tap on the `nameText` field, a cursor and a keyboard appear. However, when I hide the keyboard, the keyboard goes away but the cursor stays. How can I make the cursor invisible as well.

When I press enter from `nameText`, the cursor goes to the `phone` field and the keyboard is still visible.This is fine. But when I hide the keyboard or press enter from the `phone` field, the keyboard disappears but the cursor stays.

Is there any way (other than using `setOnEditorActionListener`) to make the cursor invisible as well in the above situations?

Comment: You are fixing nonexisitng issues. What about hardware keyboard devices for example?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

to remove the cursor from edittext you need to set

```
nameText.setFocusable(false);
```

and to visible cursor set

```
nameText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                nameText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                return false;
            }
});
```

will show the cursor in edittext...

Comment: I don't want the cursor invisible permanently. I only want it invisible when the keyboard is hidden

Comment: its working for me.. but not need to set ' nameText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);'

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas When user again touch same edittext, cursor should be visible.

Comment: I can't unserstand your concern @Sumant .. Could you told briefly?

Comment: great job!!!! working for Recycler view  too.

Comment: This works perfectly fine!

Comment: Does not work at all for me.

Comment: Works for TextInputEditText.

Answer (score 20):

`android:cursorVisible` in XML, or `setCursorVisible()` in code to hide/show the cursor, and you can use the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793093/android-edittext-soft-keyboard-show-hide-event) to determine when the keyboard has appeared & disappeared.

Comment: I don't want the cursor invisible permanently. I only want it invisible when the keyboard is hidden –

Answer (score 1):

In Xml file You can see the `<requestFocus>` attribute has been automatically added for the EditText.

So whenever the activity starts , your EditText receives the focus.

So remove it first and try...

**UpDated Answer:**

If you dont want to edit the `nameText` field

You can use

```
nameText.setEnabled(false);
```

And also If u wants to *Edit* it some case,

You can do,

```
nameText.setEnabled(true);
```

Still you can update the `nameText` field by programatically,

for Example , using `nameText.setText(Info.getname());`

If you want the user to modifications on the visible text, then you can make

```
nameText.setEnabled(true);
```

It will works as like you expects.

Comment: I already removed the `requestfocus` attribute

Comment: See the updated Answer in the post