# Showing soft keyboard when click on grid view cell

Tags: android, gridview, keyboard, user-input

I have a grid view and want to show a keyboard when the user clicks on a cell. The input of the keyboard will then appear in the cell. I've tried the code below which I got from [Android: show soft keyboard automatically when focus is on an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext/8018630#8018630) and other similar questions. I can't get the keyboard to show up, though.

Any ideas on this?

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(gridView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
```

I have tried InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED but that didn't help either.

Thanks

EDIT

The cell layout for the grid is below. I changed it to an EditText but still no keyboard. Having it as EditText doesn't look too good for me from a UI point of view. Ideally, I was the TextView and then perhaps when the user clicks it becomes an EditText so the user can enter something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="5dp" >

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/celllabel"
        android:textSize="15px" >
</EditText>
```

My idea is that it stays as a TextView. The keyboard opens and when the user clicks one letter the keyboard closes and that a letter appears in the GridCell. Is my idea possible?

Thanks

Comment: If there is no `edittext` in the cell, it is useless to show the keyboard. You cannot get the typed letter.

Comment: I''ll update my question. Thanks!

Comment: You must change all `wrap_content` to `match_parent` of `EditText` and `LinearLayout` and try again. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion:

1. Create a [custom](https://www.google.co.nz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=custom%20edittext%20android%20tutorial) `EditText`, you can [hide the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582702/disable-edittext-blinking-cursor) if you want (make it looks like a `TextView`).
2. Optimize your cell layout by removing the `LinearLayout`

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<YourCustomEditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@+id/celllabel"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="15px" >
</YourCustomEditText>
```

3. Use [`TextWatcher`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus) or [`focus`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus) interface to control the [show/hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) of the keyboard.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the help @tung-d-nguyen I will start playing now. One immediate question is why do you think I need to have a custom EditText? Can I not do everything with just the standard EditText?

Comment: @RNJ it is OK to use the default one.