# Hide android keyboard without animation?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am now showing the keyboard once tapping on a `EditText` field with the activity attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in AndroidManifest.xml so as to disable view scroll up animation. Now I hide the keyboard using the following:

```
editText.clearFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

But this would produce a scroll up animation first before hiding the keyboard. I would like to know how to hide keyboard **without this animation**.

P.S. This happens on my Android 5.1.1 Samsung Galaxy J1(2016) device.

I change to `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` for the activity and the animation still appears.

**Updates:**

I found that the animation is caused by `editText.clearFocus();`. If I remove this line, there would be no animation, but the cursor is still blinking, which is not I want.

I now used a workaround to show / hide the cursor blinking in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196130/510577) without clear the focus of the EditText.